# how to Calculate payment hours+minutes in excel

Tags: excel

let’s say I am getting paid 20$ per hour by by my employer and he wants to calculate hours+minutes (not only hours).

if I just want to calculate hours I will use =x*20 in excel

but I want to calculate hours and minutes, let’s say I worked for 1.30 hours, I can use same formula and write 1.30*20= but this doesn't work

the rate in cents is something like 33 cents, how can I just type something like 1.30 (one hour and 30 min) and get the result calculated according to 20$ per hour.

I don’t want to write in minutes because then each time I have to calculate manually then write and it will be messy.

I want to just type hours and minutes in one filed and get the result based on 20$ per hour on the other field. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use this formula: `=ROUND(HOUR(X) + MINUTE(X)/60;2)*20` where `X` is the cell with the time

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like: `=(TRUNC(x)+MOD(x,1)/0.6)*20`

```
Trunc(x) = hours
Mod(x,1) = fractional part (0.3)
Convert the Mod value to Minutes by dividing by 0.60
```

Where x = the hour.minute value. (e.g., 1.3 = 1 hour 30 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a really long way to do it.

Take the time, as 1.3 for 1 hour 30 mins, remove the minutes and convert to a number you can multiply by, add the hours back and multiply by the hourly rate.

`=(((Time-INT(Time)) * 100/60) + INT(Time))*20

Comment: Just looked up what `trunc()` does, so mine is just a long way of doing what @Achilles answer does.